# calculate integration of function

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I calculate this integral

$$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{e^t}{( 3 + e^t) \sqrt{e^t-1} }\ dt\ ?$$

I tried To assume

$$X=\sqrt{e^t-1}$$ but it didn't work

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: that have you tried?

Comment: I tried To assume X= sqrt(e^t) but it didn't work

Comment: add this approach to yopur question to enhance it a bit

Comment: There is nothing nice about this integral.  Which makes me wonder.  Where does it come from.  Are you sure you have transposed it correctly.

Comment: @DougM Integrals do not always have to be nice.

Comment: @DougM plz see my edit

Comment: @AlanTuring No they don't.  But it turns out my suspicions were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\displaystyle u = \sqrt{e^t - 1} \implies \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{e^t}{2\sqrt{e^t - 1}}$

Then your integral is essentially $$\int_{\sqrt{e-1}}^{\sqrt{e^2 - 1}} \frac{2 \, \mathrm{d}u}{4 + u^2}$$

which is a standard $\arctan$ integral.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $u^2=e^t-1$ gives an integral
$$\int_\alpha^\beta \frac{2\,du}{4+u^2}$$
which is an inverse tangent.  I'll leave you to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and finish the integral.